# How to separate a datetime into date and seconds

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, datetime, netcdf

Assume that there is a variable `time`,which is

```
<class 'netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable'>
int32 time(time)
    units: seconds since 1955-01-01
unlimited dimensions: time
current shape = (1464,)
filling off
```

and I have changed it into datetime with `time = nc.num2date(time[:],time.units)` . The output is

```
array([datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 6, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 1, 12, 0), ...,
       datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 31, 6, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 31, 12, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 31, 18, 0)], dtype=object)
```

If I want to separate the datetime  in two part, which are `date == the current date as 8 digit integer (YYYYMMDD)` and `datesec == seconds to complete current date`. For example,
this array can be spilt into two arrays( `date` and `datesec`)

```
date = array([20120101,20120101，20120101，20120101,
              20120102，20120102，...])

datesec = array ([0，21600，43200，64800，
                  0，21600，43200，64800，
                  0, 21600，43200，......])
```

Is there an efficient way to deal with it?

Comment: List comprehension + datetime methods to get year, month, day and seconds. What did you try?

Comment: The `datetime` type has methods `date` and `time`. I don't know why you want to convert dates into 8-digit integers instead of leaving them as some kind of actual usable dates that you can do arithmetic on (like a Julian days since epoch) or a useful `|S8` string, but that's easy to do with a couple lines of arithmetic, or just do the string and call `int` on it. And for times, just subtract midnight and call `total_seconds`.

Comment: `datetime` documentation shows how to extract the parts and combine them into your desired format.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

"Efficient" is a subjective term.

I don't see whats wrong with

```
date = np.array([int(dt.strftime('%y%m%d')) for dt in time])

today_midnight = datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
datesec = np.array([int((dt - today_midnight).total_seconds()) for dt in time])
```

The first one doesn't seem very useful, especially as a numpy array.

Comment: It seems that the output of `datesec` array is not the `seconds to complete current date`?

Answer (score 0):

If efficiency is what you are after, don't use object arrays. Use numpy's inbuilt `datetime64` dtype instead.

As far as I can tell `datetime64` is not quite as comfortable to use as `datetime` but it gets the job done.

You'd have to do the conversion manually, as far as I understand. Based on the metadata something like

```
timestamps = np.datetime64('1955-01-01') + your_int32_raw_data_array.astype('m8[s]')
```

should result in

```
timestamps
# array(['2012-01-01T00:00:00', '2012-01-01T06:00:00',
#        '2012-01-01T12:00:00', ..., '2012-12-31T06:00:00',
#        '2012-12-31T12:00:00', '2012-12-31T18:00:00'],
#       dtype='datetime64[s]')
```

Now, for example, getting the seconds into each day:

```
timestamps - timestamps.astype('M8[D]')
# array([    0, 21600, 43200, ..., 21600, 43200, 64800], dtype='timedelta64[s]')
```

This can be view cast into `int64` dtype if desired. (Not sure whether there are any platform dependencies here. Check in your environment to be sure.)

Getting the only the date

```
timestamps.astype('M8[D]')
# array(['2012-01-01', '2012-01-01', '2012-01-01', ..., '2012-12-31',
#        '2012-12-31', '2012-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

or

```
np.datetime_as_string(timestamps, 'D')
# array(['2012-01-01', '2012-01-01', '2012-01-01', ..., '2012-12-31',
#        '2012-12-31', '2012-12-31'], dtype='<U28')
```

If you absolutely want it in that 6-digit integer form

```
year = timestamps.astype('M8[Y]') - np.datetime64('2000')
month = timestamps.astype('M8[M]') - timestamps.astype('M8[Y]') + 1
day = timestamps.astype('M8[D]') - timestamps.astype('M8[M]') + 1

10000 * year.view(np.int64) + 100 * month.view(np.int64) + day.view(np.int64)
# array([120101, 120101, 120101, ..., 121231, 121231, 121231])
```

Comment: sorry to trouble you again. I'm not quite able to master the usage of `astype`.  For example,  the unit of `time` is `days since 2000-01-01`, and  `time=[4627.0625 4627.1875 4627.3125 4627.4375 4627.5625 4627.6875 4627.8125
 4627.9375]`. use `nc.num2date(time[:],time.units)`, we can get the similar datetime.  But if I want to split the `date` ans `datesec`,how should I modify the `astype`?

Comment: @AllenZhang do something like `time = np.datetime64('2001-01-01') + (np.array(time)*24*60*60).astype('m8[s]')` and then procceed as before.